# How to access DOM element using Selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to use jQuery selector to access the DOM deep inside.

**HTML**

```
<table>
...more stuff here
  <tr>
    <td class="foo bar clickable">
      <div>
         <div class="number">111</div> //I want to get the value "111"
         <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="foo2 bar2 clickable">
      <div>
         <div class="number">222</div>
         <div class="content"></div>
      </div> 
    </td>
  </tr>
...more stuff here
</table>
```

So a user clicks on `td` and then I want to popup the alert with **"111"** shown.

In order to access <`div class="number">111</div>` part, I wrote the jQuery selector:

```
j$(".clickable").click(function() {

   //trying to output 111               
   alert( j$("this div div.number").text());
}
```

which returns blank alert box.

```
alert( j$("this div.number").text());

alert( j$("this div .number").text());
```

Tried few combination I can think of and all gave me blank alert. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `<this>` element anywhere so `this div.number` won't work. If you want to start at `this` and find the contained `div.number`, then you want to use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
j$(this).find('div.number').text()
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`context` argument to `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

```
j$('div.number', this).text()
```

Comment: I guess I was using "this" in wrong way, now I'm clear, thank you!

Comment: @masato-san: Right, `this` is a JavaScript keyword that doesn't mean anything in a selector. You may have seen the `j$('div.number', this).text()` form of a jQuery call before but I prefer using `.find` as it is easier to tell what's going on at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {

   //trying to output 111               
   alert( $(this).find("div div.number").text());
});
```

I don't believe "this" in quotes has any meaning.

Comment: The "this" in the selector tells jQuery to look for a `<this>` element just like a "div" selector tells jQuery to look for a `<div>` element.

Comment: @mu right, I guess I didn't word that correctly.  I meant more as a reference to current element, it doesn't work.  If there were a <this> tag in the page then I guess it would match that.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and practice with fiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/

You can paste in your HTML and your JS Code and simulate any Enviroment / Framework you want.